# OpenMP seg fault (Android NDK) when trying to parallelize nested loops

Tags: c++, multithreading, android-ndk, openmp

I'm trying to use OpenMP in my Android NDK project. I have a program where I receive frames from the camera - and carry out processing on 2D matrixes. I would like to parallelize the accessing and updating of each pixel value. I have the following code, where `mat` is the 2D matrix local to a `processFrame` function, however this causes a segmentation fault:

```
unsigned y,x;
    #pragma omp parallel shared(mat) private(y,x)
            {
    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,1) collapse(2)
                //For each row
                for (y = 0U; y < _height; ++y){
                    // For each column
                    for ( x = 0U; x < _width; ++x){
                        mat.at<Vec3b>(y, x) = Vec3b(0, 0, 0);           // Background
                    }
                }
            }
```

At the start of the program, I am able to initialize the global matrix using OpenMP, as such:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,1) collapse(2)
for (unsigned y = 0U; y < height; ++y)
{
    // For each column
    for (unsigned x = 0U; x < width; ++x)
    {
        // For each channel
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (unsigned i = 0U; i < 3U; ++i)
            pixels[x][y].bgr[i] = pixels[x][y].mean_bgr[i] = 0.0F;

        pixels[x][y].scalar = pixels[x][y].pot = pixels[x][y].mean_pot = pixels[x][y].std_pot = 0.0F;
    }
}
```

The above code seems to work fine. Note: I make a call to `omp_set_nested(1);` in my main method. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I think the issue lies with the Java Native Interface. Since my `processFrame()` function is a JNI function call, the JVM limits all processing within to the main thread only (I think). I tried wrapping the processing - i.e. have a native function called by the JNI function, which uses a clone of the `Mat` image frame variable, but this also fails. I think it may not be possible to use OpenMP in this context. So my new strategy is multi-thread from the Java side - split the `Mat` image frame into blocks, and process each in a separate thread. I'm not sure if there is an easy-to-use OpenMP equivalent library in Java, but I'll look into Java concurrency. Thanks for your input!

Comment: What happens when you don't enable OpenMP.  Does the code still work?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong.  You need to give more information on `mat`.  I think you should use `schedule(static)` and there is no reason to parallelize the loop with only three iterations.

Comment: I think `mat` may be an issue. It is an OpenCV class (representing the frame I get from the camera), and the method `mat.at(x,y)` returns a the pixel at the specified location. Does OpenMP not support that?

Comment: Are you running this code from the main thread, or a background thread?

Comment: I only have one main thread. Note: I removed the call to `mat.at(x,y)` and there is still a segmentation fault. I also tried `schedule(static)` - but not luck.

Comment: Maybe you have your x and y values backwards.  For pixels you access it like pixels `pixels[x][y]` but for mat you do `mat.at<Vec3b>(y, x)` which is opposite of how you access pixels.  But to me it looks like you do `pixels` wrong not `mat`.  It's certainly not optimal for the cache the way you access pixels.  You want the last index to grow the fastest not the first.  In any case, something looks fishy.

Comment: `pixels` is a set 2d pointers - pointer to rows, each element then points to columns. That works fine. However, the problem is that any any calls to OpenMP inside my `processFrame()` function fails.

Comment: I guess you tried removing all OpenCV code from your `processFrame()` and it still crashed, right?. OpenMP has a bug if run from a background thread, but it may not be at play here since you say you call `processFrame()` from the main thread. It may be good to take a look here: http://recursify.com/blog/2013/08/09/openmp-on-android